# How to get the most expensive items into bottle caps?

Tags: fallout

Right now I'm carrying to sell a Combat Armor, a Flamethrower, a pair of Laser Rifles and Rippers, a Minigun and so on... into bottle caps.

The money equivalent for each of them would be an amount of caps I've never seen in any trader I visited. Put them all together and their value would be like +$20000... or even more than I can imagine.

And no, I don't want to use them to trade for other items, since the bottle cap currency is needed if I am to access some special things only available during dialogues: whether is to pay implants, improvements, services and the sorts.

Is there a way to reduce these items into bottle caps? Maybe some trader in the game with an enough vast amount of caps?

Comment: @TimmyJim That's Fallout 4. I'm looking for Fallout 1.

Comment: OHHHHH.  I'm sorry :X

Comment: TBH I don't think there's a way, I think that's just what Fallout is. I believe they later improved this for sequels, but in the first game you were stuck making trip after trip just sell things. Not an answer because someone is probably more clever than I am.

Comment: Hmm, I've never played fallout 1, but in 2, excess are converted to caps automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You have to break high value items down into a combination of caps and other high value/low weight items that you can sell for caps to other merchants (or to the same merchant once they get more caps in stock). Post-apocalyptic economies tend to be heavily weighted toward the barter side of the spectrum.

It’s part of the game that there is a certain amount of wastage when you’re bartering; otherwise the bartering skill would be completely useless. Certain things requiring caps is also part of the game to make those things more valuable than an inventory full of random junk. You have to work for those things a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

I believe most merchants reset the caps they have available if you stop talking to them and start the dialogue again.  (if not, they should refresh over time)

As far as where to trade, I think Zack from the Gun Runners in the Boneyard refreshes about 3500 caps.

Only other option is to trade for some stuff like ammo as well as caps.